# Apply z-index for parent child context

Tags: html, css

I have below html snippet

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <!-- Parent content -->
   <div class="child">
       <!-- Child content -->
   </div>
</div>
```

The output is like below

[image]

but `z-index` property is not working as expected here since child inherits `z-index` from it's parent. What I need do is keep the orange box on top of pink one but without changing the html(parent child element should be there as they are now), is it possible to do that?

Comment: In short, no. The non-static ancestor z-index will always be inherited by it's non-static descendants.

Comment: You could set the z-index of the parent to `auto` and the z-index of the child to `-1`. Does that work for you?

Comment: yes @Alohci. it is working. but I cannot understand how it is working. can you elaborate?

Comment: There's no such thing as `position: auto` so that defaults to `position: static`. So the parent is now a static or non-positioned element which is now in a different "flow" than any non-static or positioned element like the child which has `position: absolute`. All static elements sit at `z-index: 0` so placing any positioned elements at a negative `z-index` will appear "underneath" all static elements. See this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning)

Comment: @zer00ne - I didn't say `position: auto`, I said `z-index: auto` The parent is still positioned, but it no longer establishes a stacking context. So parent and child participate in the same stacking context and the `z-index:-1` paints it before elements with a 0 or auto z-index.